# Temporary table doesn't exist anymore in next function

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Well I am struggling with the following problem:
I create a temporary table this way:

```
mysql_query("GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP ON *.temp TO 'user'@'localhost'");

$droptemp = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp";
mysql_query($droptemp);

$maketemp = "create temporary table temp (id int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, lidnr int(6) NOT NULL, advnr int(3) NOT NULL, naam varchar(50) NOT NULL, cat varchar(20) NOT NULL, regio text NOT NULL , afbnaam varchar(30) NOT NULL, pitch text)";
mysql_query($maketemp);
```

The next thing I do is an normal insert. When I check this the table is really filled with values.

Then, later in an another function, I want to handle this table (insert or select). But then I get the message:

> 'insertTable 'db69773_vuv1.temp' doesn't exist'

The thing is that the database 'db69773_vuv1' is my regular database and not a temporary. I tried and read everything, but can't find the solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the temporary table you are using not just simply called 'temp' instead of 'db69773_vuv1.temp' ?

Comment: Well I call it temp when I create it, but 'db69773_vuv1.temp' is the name the system uses in the message so I assume 'temp' is created in the database called 'db69773_vuv1'. But that is my regular database.

Comment: are you setting a connection between creating the temporary database and trying to access it? connecting to a different database (or same one) will end your session which means your temporary tables are deleted

Comment: Well I checked but it is not that. I assume it has something to do with the database where the temp table is created in. That should not be my regular database. It should be a temporary named database.....

Comment: if you want to create a table in a temporary database you have to specify it during the create of the temporary table as you can find on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html and then skip to the note of the title Temporary Tables

Comment: Thx Jeremy, I think thats the solution. For me it is still a mistery. I'll fix an alternative.